# How do you concatenate two single rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select a bunch of single rows in bunch of dataframes and trying to make a new data frame by concatenating them together.

Here is a simple example

```
x=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],columns=["A","B","C"])

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3


a=x.loc[0,:]

A    1
B    2
C    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64

b=x.loc[1,:]
A    1
B    2
C    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64

c=pd.concat([a,b])

I end up with this:

A    1
B    2
C    3
A    1
B    2
C    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Whearas I would expect the original data frame:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

I can get the values and create a new dataframe, but this doesn't seem like the way to do it.

Comment: What about `c=pd.concat([a,b],axis=1).transpose()`?

Comment: @user322778 That seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are slicing by `index` I'd use `.iloc` and then notice the difference between `[[]]` and `[]` which return a `DataFrame` and `Series`*

```
a = x.iloc[[0]]
b = x.iloc[[1]]

pd.concat([a, b])
#   A  B  C
#0  1  2  3
#1  1  2  3
```

To still use `.loc`, you'd do something like

```
a = x.loc[[0,]]
b = x.loc[[1,]]
```

*There's a small caveat that if index 0 is duplicated in `x` then `x.loc[0,:]` will return a `DataFrame` and not a `Series`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concat two series vertically (vertical stacking), then one option is a `concat` and transpose.

Another is using `np.vstack`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a, b]), columns=a.index)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make a new dataframe from a collection of records. There's a method for that:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=["A","B","C"])
a = x.loc[0,:]
b = x.loc[1,:]
c = pd.DataFrame.from_records([a, b])
print(c)
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  1  2  3
```